# iPhone asking for Apple ID for a former roommate

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id, ios

At some point several years ago a former roommate used my phone or iTunes for something. I can't recall for what, but since then each time I get a new phone, or need to restore from a backup, I'm prompted to login with her Apple ID. In the past I would just cancel out of the login prompt a couple of times and then it wouldn't happen anymore (at least until the next time I needed a restore).

I just got the iPhone 6 and have been trying to get everything setup, but this time canceling out doesn't appear to be doing the trick. It keeps prompting me for it and will not finish the initial iCloud restore until I've logged in as her. I have no idea what app(s) or music on my phone would be attached to her account, but I would gladly delete them.

Is there a way to unassociate her account with my phone, or at the very least determine which apps are apparently tied to her account so I can remove them?

**EDIT (11/23/2014)**

The solution marked below should work. What ended up happening with my issue was that I kept declining the prompt and after several hours it finally offered to finish the sync and said that anything I hadn't logged in for would be permanently removed. I said that was ok and it finished the restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you restored your iPhone 6 from a backup of your older phone. If I understand the issue well enough, the phone keeps asking you for your friend password because you have an app that is his. If this app is on your computer in iTunes, there is a solution.

In the iTunes' list view of your Apps, right-click on an app, "Get info" (or just press <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), and, depending on your OS version, either go to the `Summary` or the `File` tab. The Apple ID of the buyer, as well as his name, will appear, and you just have to go through your files (pressing <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) until you find the culprit.

Unfortunately, iTunes cannot sort apps by buyer. However, you could sort Apps by "Date Added" in the list view to make the whole process much easier.

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping that there would be a way to do it more quickly, as there's a chance that it's a song, and going through thousands of them will be rough. A little while after I posted this question it gave me the option to end the restore and that anything not restored would be lost, so I'm hoping that will have fixed the issue once and for all. Either way, I'll probably still go through the apps and take a look. Thank you!

Comment: If it's a song, you can sort your iTunes song by iCloud Status. The ones your friend bought will appear at the top along with the ones you bought on iTunes. If you don't buy many songs from iTunes, it can be fast.

Comment: Where is the iTunes list of your apps? Is this something you'd look at on a computer synced with the phone or is it on the phone?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Unfortunately Apple has since removed the app section from iTunes. So this answer isn’t valid anymore. But to answer your question this was something you’d look on a computer synced with the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an app and you wanna find it quickly just go to updates on your phone, click 'update all' then when the phone asks for the other ID you cancel it.
The apps that will stay on the updating list after finishing the update process are the ones on the other ID.
(I know it coz I have some apps that jumped onto my phone at some point and now I'm totally gonna try changing the ID on them. Thanks, Lax!)