# How to turn off repeated prompts to sign in to itunes store from Apple ID that is not mine on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, apple-id

I keep getting repeated prompts, everytime I switch on wifi or connect to LTE I get a message that says:

`Enter the password for your Apple ID: misshammertime@yeah.net`

This is not my AppleID and never was. Nobody has used my phone to sign in with that id

I cancel and I get another prompt for a different Apple ID.
Ive tried the following things, none of which worked

- Signing out of iTunes on iOS
- Unsyncing all music from iOS
- Removing all pirated music from iTunes on Mac and resyncing to iOS.
- Turning off cellular data in iTunes & App Store in iOS.

It keeps coming back and prompting nomatter what I try. What else can I do?

iOS: 12.1

iPhone: Xs

Comment: how did it get on to YOUR phone ? Did you send a email to the misshammertime@yeah.net

Comment: Is the email address different _every time_ this happens?

Comment: The logical assumption [even if you think it could never have happened] is that an app was downloaded under that ID - This QA - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147366/85275 - used to be a good way to identify any 'foreigners' in your system, but unfortunately no longer works. Open to newer suggestions.

Comment: It’s always the same 2 apple ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things for weeks to fix this. Sadly, the only thing that worked was restoring my phone from iCloud backup.