# iPhone requesting password for wrong Apple ID when setting up Apple TV

Tags: iphone, apple-id, appletv

While setting up a brand new Apple 4k TV (tvOS 16.3), I choose the option to setup using my iPhone 13 (iOS 16.3). After confirming the popup it then prompts me for the password for my ex-partner’s Apple ID. She has never signed into my iPhone with her Apple ID and its a brand new Apple TV.

I've tried rebooting, signing out and in of iCloud on my iPhone and also signing out and in of the app store but nothing has worked. However if I attempt to use my iPad then it works as expected so it would appear to be an issue with my iPhone. Why would this happen and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Is she signed into your App Store / iTunes account, as that's separate from iCloud

Comment: If you are asking whether she has possibly signed into the app store on her iPhone with my Apple ID credentials then no, she doesn't have access to my credentials.

Comment: I mean the reverse, is her account signed in to iTunes (but not iCloud) on your phone

Comment: When you refer to iTunes I assume you mean the 'App store' app as I don't have an iTunes app on my iPhone. When I click on the top right icon in the App store I see my account details and have also tried logging out and in as part of my troubleshooting. However I do have purchase sharing enabled with her, so she does share some of my app purchases.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Odd.

Comment: Did you try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147366/237687

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know what to try, the answer relates to using iTunes which is no longer available

Comment: Have you or your ex-partner ever logged into the App Store or iTunes on your iPhone  then either get (free) or purchase an app, song, or anything else from iTunes? I'm just curious, guessing at anything that might be related.Confused since I would have thought that if you choose to setup with your other devices it shouldn't ask you to log into your Apple ID at all. When you use your iPad, does it ask you to log in also? Does it ask you to log in on the Apple TV or the iPad? And what about when you use your iPhone?

Comment: May be late, but check on iPhone in the settings /passwords if you have multiple appleId registered for daw2.apple.com